# I need to select top five and bottom five numbers from a list of 60 numbers

Tags: mysql

I need to select top five and bottom five numbers from a list of 60 numbers based on their count.

I have a table - scores
query to select top five

```
SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```

gets the top five

```
SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY count ASC LIMIT 5
```

gets both sets of numbers -

what would be the best way to combine these two queries to return one set (make these into one query)

join?

I have tried this but get an error on the order by

```
SELECT * FROM scores order by count desc limit 5 union all select * from scores order by count asc limit 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM scores 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT * 
FROM scores 
ORDER BY count ASC LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: I tried that and this is the error returned  #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: update - that code worked once parns have been added

Comment: (
SELECT * 
FROM scores
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5
)
UNION (

SELECT * 
FROM scores
ORDER BY count ASC 
LIMIT 5
)